# Angular 2 ngClass not evaluating my expression when checking against condition

Tags: angular, expression, angular2-directives

I have an expression in Angular 2 called selectedState. The expression evaluates to one of five properties inside of const. Depending on which is clicked it changes the class name.

```
                    <button
                        class="button button--secondary"
                        [ngClass]="selectedState">
                        <div class="u-maxX u-centerX">
                            <span>Button</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </button>
```

"selectedState" will return whichever item is clicked; default, is-hovering, is-active, disabled, and loading.

e.g. If I click is-hovering it will return

```
                    `<button
                        class="button button--secondary is-hovering">
                        <div class="u-maxX u-centerX">
                            <span>Button</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </button>`
```

Now when I change the syntax like so.

```
                    <button
                        class="button button--primary"
                        [ngClass]="{selectedState: type === 'primary'}">
                        <div class="u-maxX u-centerX">
                            <span>Button</span>

                        </div>
                    </button>
```

Now "selectedState" evaluates to the string "selectedState" instead of being dynamic and changing like before. How can I keep the dynamic behavior while checking for type === 'primary'? I need to check for type because there are several types on the page. I need each type to ONLY affect one button otherwise it will affect all the buttons on the page.

Comment: *""selectedState" evaluates to "selectedState" every time"* - that's how object literals work! Have you considered building the appropriate object in a getter method in the class, rather than trying to do it all in the template?

Comment: In the first example selectedState evaluates to 1/5 options. E.g. default, hover, active, disabled, and loading. In the second it evaluates to just "selectedState."

Comment: You may need to add more information about the expected behaviour here. Like do you want it to be `class="button button--primary selectedState"` when `type === 'primary'`?

Comment: @HarryNinh. Please see updated example.

Comment: Yes, because in the first example it's not the name of a property an object literal. Computed names are not yet supported in templates: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13855

Comment: @London804 can you share you component also? How do you set 'type' and selectedState?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep as much logic out of your templates as possible, so either bind `[ngClass]="someVariable"` and mutate that variable by calling functions, or bind `[ngClass]="someFunction()"` and have that function return the appropriate class name based on some set of conditions.

For example, have a button that calls the setIsHovering function, and another button that calls the setIsActive function etc., then define those functions:

```
setIsActive() {
    this.selectedState = "isActive";
}

setIsHovering() {
    this.selectedState = "isHovering";
}
```

And define the ngClass as:

```
[ngClass]="selectedState"
```

Or, define a selectedState function:

```
selectedState() {
    if(this.isHoveringStateVariable == true) {
         this.selectedState = "isHovering";
    } else if (this.isActiveStateVariable == true) {
          this.selectedState = "isActive";
    }
}
```

And define the ngClass as:

```
[ngClass]="selectedState()"
```

Obviously replace this.isHoveringStateVariable with whatever logic is appropriate for determining what the actual current state is.

Comment: Downvotes without comments aren't particularly helpful. Anyone care to explain what the problem with this answer is?

Comment: I'm not the one who voted down, but you shouldn't call functions from your template because they will be execute on every change detection cycle.

Comment: That's a performance decision, and also one of two options I listed, the first being to bind to a variable and mutate that through buttons or some other change in state. I use both in my applications, and I have some large applications. Sometimes you want to reevaluate classes on each change detection cycle and not have to worry about mutating your class variables manually, for example on a nested nav component in a container as a result of a route change on a outlet where binding to a function is cleaner and faster than triggering events or piping changes through a service to sync the nav.

Comment: I don't think it's your best interest to reevaluate classes every change detection. Even if you don't feel it in your application it's a performance issue and cause's a lot of unnecessary functions to be called..

Comment: @StephenR.Smith I up voted your answer.  You shouldn't call functions inside of ngClass for performance issues, however mutating my variable by using an outside function got me the results I wanted. Thank you.